# Making files not accessible in node js

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I'm using WebStrom to create a node js website.

1) What template of project should  I choose (AngularJS, node express etc)? I do use angular-js but I also need a server side.

2) What are the best practices for the project structure?

3) How I make the server side js files not accessible from the browser? I created a few projects from the different templates and I managed to reach every single js file by writing its path in the browser.

Any help will be profoundly appreciated!

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per SO question. 1. Product recommendations are off-topic. 2. Too broad and too opinion based (so off-topic). 3. That is not normal, but we can't tell what you did wrong without seeing what you did. You need to provide a [test case](http://sscce.org/). Since you didn't provide one, the question is off-topic.

Comment: I don't know at all what the project structure is supposed to look like and therefore where to place server side files and client side files. If I had known that I did something right, I could have asked a more specific question. I'm coming from .net background and this is my very first serious node js project. I didn't ask for a product recommendation but for a WebStorm project template that would fit my need. If there're no best practices, I would be glad to get any practice that works.

Comment: I guess a good first step could be to install [express-generator](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html). It will create an initial express project folder structure for you where you can take a look at one way of organizing files. The truth is though, there are no real rules on how to do this. If the code is right, the system will work so experiment with different settings and explore more into node and you'll find your flavor. Research, Research, Research !!!

Comment: WebStorm already have a few pre-built project structures. I only need to know which of them fits for a website with both server side and static html files. Anyway I'd be glad if someone told me what makes a file accessible or not accessible from the browser on node js. For example on IIS, the IIS itself decides according to the file extension. So wha't the such esoteric secret on node js? how I make a file accessible or not? I could research for this piece of information for hours or days but I hoped someone would know.

Comment: Node apps typically have routes defined specifically for the endpoints you define, for example `/about` or `/contact`. You can define all additional random routes to redirect to a 404 page. Express makes routes simple. Notice this has nothing to do with Angular. Node+Express are server side, Angular is frontend

Comment: I use the "Node.js Express App" template which contains directories such as "public" and "routes", but I'm still able to see any js file on the browser including "app.js"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using templating. I personally like using handlebars but there are many different options out there.

https://github.com/fixiecoder/node-express-handlebars-boilerplate

This is a link to a very basic node express application that uses handlebars templates. There are also many tutorials that you can use to learn more.

The line `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` in the server.js file is what is used to specify a public folder that is the only thing that the browser will be able to access. Everything outside of this is private to the server.

The best thing you could do though it just do some basic tutorials from start to finish to understand how it all fits together.